# Run Silex Application in Command Line

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'd like to run a [Silex Application](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) like this in Command Line:

```
$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
  return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

I think for that purpose, i'd have to pass [Symfony's Request Object](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)  as first parameter to the run method, but i've got no idea, where to set the Url-Path to make it work. Any Ideas? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use Request::create() method to create the Request object and pass that into run()

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
list($_, $method, $path) = $argv;
$request = Request::create($path, $method);
$app->run($request);
```

And then on the command line:

```
$ php console.php GET /
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use silex in a command line, you need to use the [Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html), here a tutorial for silex: http://beryllium.ca/?p=481

Then you are able to call a twig (symfony) service, and to forward an action !

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Comment: Thanks , i already use the console component. built it with this tutorial. the question is, how do i get the result from e.g. '/hello/sybio', from the get route I registered?

Comment: run() outputs it onto the console.

Comment: Webarchive version of the tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20121108160050/http://beryllium.ca/?p=481